# how to create graph by edge and vertex txt file?

Tags: networkx

[edge : vertex[coordinate]--vertex[coordinate]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHAt.png)

how to feed the vertex and edge to a graph? I have tried by myself, but have problems.

```
import string
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()  # 建立一个空的无向图G
with open("HLN-12-1vertices.txt") as node_list:
  for eachline in node_list:
      G.add_node()


with open("HLN-12-1edges.txt") as edge_list:
    for eachline in edge_list:
        G.add_node()
print("number of edges:", G.number_of_edges()) # 输出边的数量
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you aren't actually passing the node name to the `G.add_node` parameter. If each line in your vertices text file has the name of the node, you can pass the variable `eachline` to the function (you might have to parse the file for end of line characters and other parsing if the file is formatted differently.

When you're reading the edges text file, the code again doesn't pass the edge data to the function, and you since you're passing the edge information, you need to use the function `G.add_edge()` instead. This function takes the parameters 'u_of_edge' and 'v_of_edge' which are the two endpoints of the edge.

Lastly, the function `G.add_edge` already adds new vertices to the graph if they aren't already created, so if all your vertices have an edge in the edges text file you can skip reading from the vertices text file.

Comment: yes, But  I have found that networkx can't use 3D vertices. This is a big problem